# How to use Jackson for parse object follow json type?

Tags: java-8, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

I have two Json objects like :

- Object 1

```json
{
    "value": {
        "data": [
            "John",
            "Justin",
            "Tom"
        ],
        "isGraduated": false
    }
}
```

- Object 2

```json
{
    "value": {
        "data": {
            "info": {
                "background": {
                    "primarySchool" : "A school",
                    "univeristy": "X univeristy"
                },
                "name": "John",
                "gender": "male",
                "dayOfBirth": "1995-04-24"
            }
        },
        "isGraduated": false
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize the `data` field to list of strings or class(I've already declared) by using Jackson?

### Edit

- Add class Info declaration.

```java
public class Info {
    @JsonProperty("background")
    private BackGround backGround;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("gender")
    private String gender;
    @JsonProperty("dayOfBirth")
    private String dayOfBirth;

    public static class BackGround {
        @JsonProperty("primarySchool")
        private String primarySchool;
        @JsonProperty("univeristy")
        private String univeristy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your class that you've already declared as well

Comment: I've added class I've already declared.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JSON objects, there is no way you can figure out what will be there in `data` parameter. So you can use `JsonNode` as type for `data` parameter.

*Note: This is the object hierarchy I have created to represent JSON objects*

```
@ToString
class Wrapper {
    private Value value;
    
    // getter & setter
}

@ToString
class Value {
    private JsonNode data;
    private Boolean isGraduated;

    // getter & setter
}

@ToString
class Data {
    private Info info;

    // getter & setter
}

@ToString
class Info {
    private Background background;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String dayOfBirth;

    // getter & setter

    @ToString
    static class Background {
        private String primarySchool;
        private String univeristy;

        // getter & setter
    }
}
```

Then you can check the node type before deserialize between `List<String>` and `Info.calss` like this,

```
JsonNodeType type = value.getValue().getData().getNodeType();
```

You will see `type = JsonNodeType.ARRAY` if the json object is type 1 and `type = JsonNodeType.OBJECT` if the json object is type 2.

Check this exaple,

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//        String s = "{\"value\":{\"data\":[\"John\",\"Justin\",\"Tom\"],\"isGraduated\":false}}";
        String s = "{\"value\":{\"data\":{\"info\":{\"background\":{\"primarySchool\":\"A school\",\"univeristy\":\"X univeristy\"},\"name\":\"John\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"dayOfBirth\":\"1995-04-24\"}},\"isGraduated\":false}}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Wrapper wrapper = om.readValue(s, Wrapper.class);

        JsonNodeType type = wrapper.getValue().getData().getNodeType();

        if (type == JsonNodeType.ARRAY) {
            List<String> data = om.convertValue(wrapper.getValue().getData(), new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
            System.out.println(data);
        } else if (type == JsonNodeType.OBJECT) {
            Data data = om.convertValue(wrapper.getValue().getData(), Data.class);
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the general approach but approach for your specific case

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(jsonContent);
JsonNode data = root.get("value").get("data");

if (data.has("info")) {
    Info result = mapper.convertValue(data.get("info"), Info.class);
    // handle result as Info instance
} else {
    List<String> result = mapper.convertValue(data, new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
    // handle result as list of strings
}
```